# Outlined triangle svg animation

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I've created a simple outlined triangle. The problem i need to solve - is to create animation of filling the gap between triangles from bottom to top.

When i am using the fill option for polygons, the fill area overlaps the other triangle, so that there is no "hole" in the shape.

```css
body{
  background: #7085EA;
}

.triangle-container{
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.triangle {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
  <svg height="500" width="500">
    <polygon points="250,100 100,400 400,400" class="triangle"/>
    <polygon points="250,180 160,360 340,360" class="triangle"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Initial codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/taki-taki/pen/OJLQrdB).

The area that needs to be filled is shown on screenshot here

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use this path instead of the 2 triangles: `<path d="M250,100 L100,400 400,400 250,100 M250,180 L340,360 160,360 250,180z" class="triangle" />`  and fill it with a color or with a pattern. Try this pattern: `<pattern id="lines" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="5" height="5" >
       <line  x2="5" stroke="#fff" />
    </pattern>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the advices here, and an another SO [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645053/is-it-possible-to-make-svg-circle-fill-color-from-bottom-to-top-based-on-percent), came up with the following solution:

```css
body{
  background: #7085EA;
}

.triangle-container{
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.triangle {
  stroke: #fff;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
   <svg height="500" width="500">
      <linearGradient id="loading" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#fff">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s" begin="0s"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#fff">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  begin="0s"/>
          </stop>
      </linearGradient>
     <path d="M250,100 L100,400 400,400 250,100 M250,180 L340,360 160,360 250,180z" class="triangle" fill="url(#loading)"></path>
   </svg>
</div>
```